# Weave columns in data frame using zip

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has the columns `x`, `y`, `z`, `x2`, `y2`, `z2`.

What I would like to do is weave the columns together so they look like:

```
x  y  z
x2 y2 z2
```

For example:

```
x   y   z   x2  y2  z2
1   1   1   2   2   2
2   2   2   3   3   3
3   3   3   4   4   4
```

I want it to look like this:

```
x   y   z
1   1   1
2   2   2
2   2   2
3   3   3
3   3   3
4   4   4
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with the zip function?

Comment: Do you want to combine, say both `x` and `x2` and then sort their values?

Comment: def to_array(dataframe):
    weaved = np.empty((len(dataframe) * 2, 3))
    weaved[0::2] = dataframe[['x', 'y', 'z']].values
    weaved[1::2] = dataframe[['x2', 'y2', 'z2']].values
    return weaved # I've accomplished this with the function, but I was wondering if the same would be possible with zip, and if it would be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! It is called `reshape` and can be done by Numpy. Check this out:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 3), columns=df.columns[:3])
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting my answer and selecting it as accepted answer! Thanks

Comment: would the same be possible using a zip? ivallesp

Comment: What does -1 mean? Great solution btw

Comment: O don’t know how to use a zip for that. -1 means to calculate that dimension automatically given the other :)